# Azure Custom Vision returning {"code":"NotFoundIteration","message":"Invalid iteration"}

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I noticed that Custom Vision is now returning the message {"code":"NotFoundIteration","message":"Invalid iteration"} instead of the expected (and previously provided) results.

Something has recently changed on the API call?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have seen the same issue happened and the latest news I got from support team is: Problem was identified ; due to recently introduced defect some published models were removed ; after which prediction requests against these published models would fail.  The original bug was fixed and a repair program was ran that put back the missing published models. So I think your issue should be fixed now as well. If not, please let us know. Thank you.

Regards,
Yutong

Comment: Hi Yutong,

Thanks for your feedback, publishing a new iteration I was able to call again the service.

Comment: Glad to know, could you please verify my answer if you think it's helpful. And please let us know if you have further challenge for this.